# Why does JSON have extra square bracket in output?

Tags: php, json

My JSON (decoded) has extra square brackets after the `subdivisions` part, so I can't target it like I would target the other parts using, for example, `$resultArray['country']['geoname_id'];`. Why is there an extra pair of square brackets there?

```
string(1461) "{"country":{"iso_code":"CA","names":{"pt-BR":"Canadá","es":"Canadá","ru":"Канада","en":"Canada","zh-CN":"加拿大","fr":"Canada","de":"Kanada","ja":"カナダ"},"confidence":99,"geoname_id":6251999},"location":{"longitude":-79.4886,"latitude":43.7496,"time_zone":"America/Toronto","accuracy_radius":10},"subdivisions":[{"iso_code":"ON","names":{"en":"Ontario","zh-CN":"安大略","pt-BR":"Ontário","ja":"オンタリオ州","ru":"Онтарио"},"confidence":93,"geoname_id":6093943}],"postal":{"confidence":17,"code":"M3J"},.....
```

I'm referring to

```
"subdivisions":[{"iso_code":"ON"
```

This part, and the closing one. Why is subdivisions the only thing to have square brackets?

Comment: It is an array representation, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-json--active-8817

Comment: Why is that the only part that has it? And how do I target the parts in it to assign them to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Subdivisions it's an array, in JSON, these are objects:

`{key:value}`

And these are arrays:

`[{key1:value1},{key2:value2}]`

Just like javascript. So in this case, subdivisions can have multiple values, if you decode this in PHP with json_decode() you'll get an array with one object in.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `$data = json_decode($string, true);` //set true for associative array, you get:

```
array (
  'country' => 
  array (
    'iso_code' => 'CA',
    'names' => 
    array (
      'pt-BR' => 'Canadá',
      'es' => 'Canadá',
      'ru' => 'Канада',
      'en' => 'Canada',
      'zh-CN' => '加拿大',
      'fr' => 'Canada',
      'de' => 'Kanada',
      'ja' => 'カナダ',
    ),
    'confidence' => 99,
    'geoname_id' => 6251999,
  ),
  'location' => 
  array (
    'longitude' => -79.4886000000000052523319027386605739593505859375,
    'latitude' => 43.7496000000000009322320693172514438629150390625,
    'time_zone' => 'America/Toronto',
    'accuracy_radius' => 10,
  ),
  'subdivisions' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'iso_code' => 'ON',
      'names' => 
      array (
        'en' => 'Ontario',
        'zh-CN' => '安大略',
        'pt-BR' => 'Ontário',
        'ja' => 'オンタリオ州',
        'ru' => 'Онтарио',
      ),
      'confidence' => 93,
      'geoname_id' => 6093943,
    ),
  ),
  'postal' => 
  array (
    'confidence' => 17,
    'code' => 'M3J',
  ),
)
```

Access data:

```
$data['subdivisions'][0]['iso_code'];
$data['subdivisions'][0]['names']['en'];
```

You might need to analyze the json to see if you get several values in **subdivisions** before implementing what you are doing